# How to add multiple row of data from sql database to the datagridview which has the same id in database VB.NET SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba, vb.net, datagridview

Problem is my code retrieves multiple row of data from the database which has the same invoice id. However, it displays only the first row of data in the datagridview.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PtHZM.png)

Note: the invoice id is not a primary key but a foreign key

I have tried using data reader and this is based on another web source.

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Public Class payment
    Dim con As New SqlConnection("server = DESKTOP-SNQAJCQ;Database=SDP;Integrated security=SSPI")
    Dim dr As SqlDataReader
    Private Sub btnsearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnsearch.Click

        Dim i As Integer
        con.Open()

        Dim searchQuery As String = "SELECT * From Order_ WHERE id=@id "

        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(searchQuery, con)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = txtinvoice.Text
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
        While dr.Read
            i += 1
            dgwPayment.Rows.Add(dr.Item("item_description").ToString,
                                dr.Item("unit_price").ToString,
                                dr.Item("weight_").ToString,
                                dr.Item("quantity").ToString,
                                dr.Item("total").ToString,
                                dr.Item("special_remarks").ToString)
        End While

    End Sub
End Class
```

My expected result is that it should display all rows of data that has the same invoice id.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSP6m.png)

Comment: Looks like sql query search for an order based on order id `SELECT * From Order_ WHERE id=@id`, but you mention that you want display all orders based on invoice id, shouldn't you query be then `SELECT * From Order_ WHERE InvoiceId=@id`

Comment: oh yeah wait let me change n see if tht works

Comment: thanks bro that was a mistake. Thanks for correcting me